# Creating web service in cxf throwing "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException"

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am creating saveral web services using CXF. All the web services are working fine but only in one I am getting "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException". My web service code is mentioned below.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cxf/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

applicationontext-IconeService.xml

```
<bean id="historiqueVlWsService" class="com.HistoriqueVlWsService" >
    </bean>
<bean id="iconeSService" class="com.IconeWSImpl"></bean>
    <jaxws:server id="historiqueVlWS" serviceClass="com.HistoriqueVlWsInterface" address="/historiqueVlWsService" serviceBean="#historiqueVlWsService">
    </jaxws:server>
    <jaxws:server id="iconeWS" serviceClass="com.IconeWS" address="/iconeSService" serviceBean="#iconeSService">
    </jaxws:server>
```

From above one with id = "iconeWS" giving error.

Log is attached below.

```
18:10:38,254 INFO  [STDOUT] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iconeWS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) [spring-web-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910) [jbossweb.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389) [jbossweb.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321) [jboss-web-service.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145) [jboss-web-service.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461) [jboss.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122) [jboss.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97) [jboss.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264) [jboss-mbeans.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668) [jboss-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46) [jboss-system-jmx.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [jboss-deployers-spi.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [jboss-deployers-spi.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(Deploy
18:10:38,271 INFO  [STDOUT] ersImpl.java:1172) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699) [jboss-deployers-impl.jar!/:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.0.10.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256) [jboss-system.jar!/:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461) [jboss-bootstrap.jar:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221) [run.jar:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556) [run.jar:5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:339) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86) [cxf-rt-core-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490) [cxf-rt-core-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:697) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550) [cxf-rt-core-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265) [cxf-rt-core-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1639) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1580) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510) [spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1136) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202) [na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363) [na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574) [na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:330) [cxf-api-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:328) [cxf-api-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.cr
18:10:38,283 INFO  [STDOUT] eateContext(JAXBContextCache.java:328) [cxf-api-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:228) [cxf-api-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:494) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:337) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
18:10:38,285 ERROR [[/icone-web]] Exception lors de l'envoi de l'?v?nement contexte initialis? (context initialized) ? l'instance de classe d'?coute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iconeWS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:321)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
```

Please help someone as i am new to cxf and after searching on net also didn't got a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472) [jaxb-impl.jar!/:2.1.12]

This is not a CXF problem. Seems you have a problem with a JAXB annotation in some of the beans involved in the service creation.

Also note that you do not need to include jaxb-impl.jar in your deployment Because JDK includes JAXB since jdk1.6

Comment: But the same web service is already written using xfire and there it is working fine. And if the problem is because of Jaxb then there also this problem should come.

Comment: Have you changed JDK or JAXB version or include new beans? Please include your beans and annotations to take a look

Comment: No I have not changed anything neither JDK nor Jaxb or any bean.. but I have to change the JDK version to 8 that I thot will do later.

Comment: It is possible that CXF performs JAXB initialization in different way that XFIRE does. May be the Java to WDSL generator or the SOAP converter have changed. Really I do not know, but the exception points to JAXB. Include your used annotation and we could see.